# Update Panel on master page refreshes child page update panels also

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a master page on which at the top i show a div using jquery. in that div i have a **update panel with a checkbox** with autopostback true. basically i want to make a menu to change settings without full page postback.it works perfectly

but i have a certain child page in which i have a gallery which has a update panel inside which is a datalist to be able to change images without postback.

problem is when i click on the master page checkbox the update panels on the child page also get refreshed..why this happens???

also for the master page updatepanel i have **update mode** to **conditional** and **childeren as triggers** to **false** and i have set an **asynchpostback trigger** for **CheckBox1_CheckChanged** event.

so am i doing anything wrong...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-right: 2px">
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               notify me of new buzz through email</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                     <asp:HiddenField ID="bmStatus" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CheckBox1" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

do i have to set any other settings on the child page update panels...i will post the child page update panel code if asked!!!

Thanks a lot

Comment: How is your asynchpostbacktrigger defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UpdatePanel is a full postback no matter what.  I recommend removing ChildrenAsTriggers="False" unless you have some other reason for needing it.  Below is a link to what this setting does. You may need multiple UpdatePanels to achieve your desired functionality.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/mref/P_System_Web_UI_UpdatePanel_ChildrenAsTriggers.aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying.....changing the value to true doesnt solve the problem...yet thanks to ur link and watching some videos on update panel, i am now able to understand Update Panels much better...when i find a solution i will post it here......